# Cchanging image opacity on mouseup event

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I've been trying to work out how to change image opacities on mouse events. so far I've come up with:

```
    <img src="image.png" style="opacity:1;filter:alpha(opacity=100)"
onmouseup="this.style.opacity=0.4;this.filters.alpha.opacity=40" />
```

This works great when the image I want to change is the one that is clicked, but I want to change the opacity of another image when you click this on; click an image, make another one appear sort of thing.

I know that the answer has something to do with `this.style.opacity` but I can't seem to work it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this

```
<img src="image.png" style="opacity:1;filter:alpha(opacity=100)"
onclick="ChangeImage()" />
 <img src="image.png" id="image2" style="opacity:20;filter:alpha(opacity=100)"
onclick="ChangeImage()" />
```

And javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ChangeImage(){
var image2= document.getElementById('image2');
   //do your work here for image2 
   image2.style.opacity='1';

}
</script>
```